# How to prove this equation? (gradient)

Tags: vector-analysis

I have to solve the [Question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQkoe.png), where I have to prove the relation

> $$\nabla\cdot(f\textbf v) = f\nabla \cdot  \textbf v+ (\nabla f)\cdot\textbf v$$

And I have the question:

> *Is there any difference between $\text{grad} f$ and $f \text{grad}$ ?*

Thanks.

Comment: In the question the vector operations indicated is not only grad but also div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question you ask *Is there any difference between $\text{grad} f$ and $f \text{grad}$ ?* The answer to that question is **yes**.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. So we have that

> $$\text{grad}f := \nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}, \dots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)$$

Where $f = f(\vec{x})$ for $\vec{x} = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$. So we have that $\text{grad}f$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now

> $$f \text{grad} = f(\vec{x})\nabla = \left(f(\vec{x})\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}, f(\vec{x})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}, \dots, f(\vec{x})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right)$$

Is an operator that *acs* in the vetors of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. So they are quite different things, one is a vector in the space and the other is an operator that acs on the space.

---

I suppose that your question is, for a vector $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, you have to prove the equality

$$\nabla (f(\vec{x})\vec{v}) = f(\vec{x})\nabla\vec{v} + (\nabla f(\vec{x}))\vec{v}$$

Note that $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Using Einstein summation notation

$$\nabla(f\vec{v}) = \partial_\color{red}{i}(fv^\color{red}{i}) = f\partial_\color{red}{i}v^\color{red}{i}+v^\color{red}{i}\partial_\color{red}{i}f = f(\nabla\vec{v})+v^\color{red}{i}(\nabla f)_\color{red}{i} = f(\nabla \vec{v})+\vec{v}\nabla f$$

Where $i = 1,2,3,\dots,n$ and $\partial _i := \partial/\partial x_i$ and we use that for two vectors $a,b \in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that

$$\vec{a}\vec{b} = \sum_\color{red}{i}a_\color{red}{i}b_\color{red}{i} \stackrel{\text{Einstein}}{= }a_\color{red}{i}b^\color{red}{i}$$

Comment: Thanks, i understand the difference now.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to apply the product rule.

By definition we have:

$\nabla \cdot (f \bar{v}) = \frac{f\bar{v_x}}{\partial x} + \frac{f\bar{v_y}}{\partial y} + \frac{f\bar{v_z}}{\partial z} $

= $ \bar{v_x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \bar{v_y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \bar{v_z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} +  f\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial x} + f\frac{\partial v_y}{\partial y} + f\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}$

= $(\nabla f) \cdot v + f\nabla \cdot v $

Comment: it is useful, thx